# $L^1_{loc}$ bounded or compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've studied Functional Analysis and Sobolev Spaces from different references and what I noticed is that sometimes people consider $L^1_{loc}$ to be defined by integrating on bounded domain and sometimes on compact one. The difference is crucial since, for instance, for the function $\frac{1}{x}$ we get that for the "bounded" definition
$$
\frac{1}{x} \not\in L^1_{loc}((0,1))
$$
but for the compact definition
$$
\frac{1}{x} \in L^1_{loc}((0,1))
$$

Comment: Maybe the think of a a bounded domain s.t. $\bar{U} \subset \subset \Omega$?

Comment: Usually: compact. $1/x$ is perfectly fine as an element of $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(0,1)$, its basically the same as $x$ on $(0,\infty)$ which is $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$.